# Optimize 5 million records SQL query (use join or not?!)

Tags: query-performance, optimization, join, subquery

I have a table for `products` that contains almost **5 million records**.

I have a column for the product category `(product_category)`. That it is for now of type `INT(11)` and it is an index and refers to another table (`categories` table)
The categories table **only contains the name of the category**.

*Category names are static and never updated nor edited.*

What is the **best optimal** solution to always get the product category name in the fastest query?

- Using **join method**.
- Using **subquery method**.
- Store the **category name** as a `string` in the products table.

If any other suggestions will be great, and what is the best optimal solution from the mentioned option above?

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: @ErikDarling, What is it that I need to give an explanation more about?

Comment: Click the link, read the post. It’s all in there.

Comment: We need to see the full query, and tables and indexes, and please show the query plan (`EXPLAIN` or whatever). Tagging your database would be helpful also obvously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, storing the data in a single table is almost always going to be the "*fastest*" way to materialize the data for reads. But in a database system, you run into issues with data maintenance and accuracy when you denormalize your data as such. You can even run into hindering performance of your database when data is being written and read from the table concurrently.

For example, let's say you want to display the unique list of `categories` in your application. Well you'd have to run a query such as `SELECT DISTINCT CategoryName FROM products` to do so, likely scanning the whole 5 million row table. Not great for performance. And what if one day a group of `products` change in a way that makes them more appropriate to be part of a different `category`?...updating those records would lock the table and / or get locked waiting on the aforementioned query to finish, whenever the app is ran. Again, not great performance-wise.

There are numerous other reasons you should normalize your data as well. Storing the distinct list of `categories` to it's own table is likely going to be the **best for overall performance**, data accuracy, and management. 5 million rows is actually not a big table, and `JOIN`ing to it with tiny tables like `categories` is going to be quite fast (perhaps a few milliseconds different than if you stored everything in a single table), when indexed appropriately. Furthermore, if you're not always reading all 5 million `products` out of the database system, rather a subset at a time, then it doesn't really matter how big the `products` table is (again when indexed properly).

Comment: Thank you so much, this for sure makes a lot of sense. So I will just proceed with the normalization process (keep the category id and use a different table for categories). just one thing. What do you suggest to get the category name in the query? should I use a (subquery) or use join?

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi No problem. As my answer mentioned, `JOIN`ing will be quite fast enough (when indexed properly). Subqueries, while useful for certain use cases, shouldn't be your first go-to when relating two tables together as there's a few reasons you can run into issues that way. Use the operation that was designed to be most performant for relating two tables together, `JOIN`.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you again!